# Windows Installer package for VSTO addin In Word 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, vsto

I have a Visual Studio installer in VS 2013. This works fine for Word 2010 and Word 2013 but on Word 2007 it doesn't install correctly although the installer runs and says its successfully installed. After install, when I open Word 2007, the addin isn't ticked. If I then tick the addin and press ok, nothing happens and then if I look again, the addin is no longer ticked. If I look in the registry, the install package has failed to create the registry setting I have in my install package. Even if I manually create these, I still have the same issue in Word which suggests something else in the installer hasn't works although it seems to have put all the files in the right place, so i'm quite confused.

Note that I'm confident the addin itself is all fine in Word 2007 because when I build and run the addin with Word 2007, it all works correctly so i don't think there should be an issue with PIA's or any reference in the project etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: When I change the installation setting to write to current user instead of local machine, the registry correctly gets written too and the addin appears ticked and can see the ribbon. However when running anything on the ribbon that reads the project settings, it doesn't work. I have found that double clicking the vsto file fixes this, but i shouldn't need to do this.

UPDATE2: I have found a solution to the second part of my question (the need to double click the vsto for the settings to work). The manifest file if the registry must start "file:///" for Office 2007.

Comment: From what I know for 2007 you can install/register only per-user addins. Other than that nothing special should be required.

Comment: Many thanks Bogdan. So that would explain why I had more success with current user compared to local machine. I'm still stuck on why I would need to double click the vsto file to be able to read the project settings. This isn't required for Word 2010 or Word 2013